Pushing Image built by Kaniko to ECR
I am running a service in AWS ECS. From inside the container, I am trying to build and push a new image (using Kaniko) to ECR but I am facing the following error every time:
error checking push permissions -- make sure you entered the correct tag name, and that you are authenticated correctly, and try again: checking push permission for "${account_id}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${repo_name}:${tag_name}”: POST https://${account_id}.dkr.ecr.${region}.amazonaws.com/${location}: unexpected status code 401 Unauthorized: Not Authorized

Here is the Shell Script I am using for building the image:
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}

/kaniko/executor --dockerfile Dockerfile_UK \
    --destination ${repo_tag_name} \
    --build-arg account_id=${account} \
    --build-arg env=${exec_stage} \
    --build-arg python_version=${python_version} \
    --build-arg model_class=${model_class} \
    --build-arg model_pickle=${model_pickle} \
    --build-arg model_attributes=${model_attributes} \
    --build-arg requirements=${requirements} \
    --build-arg predictor=${predictor} \
    --build-arg http_proxy=${http_proxy} \
    --build-arg https_proxy=${https_proxy} \
    --build-arg region=${region} \
    --cache=true \
    --insecure-pull \
    --insecure \
    --skip-tls-verify \
    --verbosity=info \
    --snapshotMode=redo \
    --cleanup \
    --use-new-run \
    --no-push=false \
    --tarPath=/kaniko/saved_images \
    --digest-file=/kaniko/digest \
    --oci-layout-path=/kaniko/oci-layout \
    --log-format=text \
    --log-timestamp \
    --skip-unused-stages=true \
    --registry-mirror=${ecr_reg} \
    --registry=${ecr_reg} \
    --username=AWS \
    --password=${password}


My service is up and running and it executes all the tasks perfectly such as consuming messages from the message broker, downloading artefacts from s3 bucket. But whenever I am trying to push the image built by Kaniko to ECR, it fails.
I'm expecting that the image should be pushed to ECR without having any docker dependency

The command aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region} returns a password, that you then have to use to actually login to ECR. You are not capturing the output of that command or trying to use it to login to ECR in any way.

Thanks @MarkB for pointing that out. I am storing the password: password=$(aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}). My shell script is running successfully but I can't find the image in the desired repo in ECR

Edit your question to show the new script then. You have to provide us with enough info to reproduce your issue if you want help.
